# Variation on Hermite Generating Function

Tags: special-functions

I am having trouble using the Hermite generating function to determine $e^{t^2}\cos(2xt)$. 
I know the generating function is $e^{2tx-t^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{t^n}{n!}H_n(x)$ but can't seem to get anywhere. Can anyone help direct me on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One may replace $t$ by $it$, getting
$$
e^{2itx+t^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^ni^n\frac{t^n}{n!}H_n(x)
$$ then one may take the real part:
$$
e^{t^2}\cos2xt=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{t^{2n}}{(2n)!}H_{2n}(x)
$$ where we have assumed that $t,x$ are real numbers.

Comment: Where does the cosine come from? I can see how removing the imaginary would give the right side but not how you got the left.

Comment: From De Moivre's formula: $e^{i\alpha}=\cos(\alpha)+i \sin(\alpha)$. Do you see it? Here: $e^{2itx}=\cos(2tx)+i \sin(2tx)$

Comment: ah okay that makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: @Aksel'sRose You are welcome.